# How to search in process memory (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program which will search in a memory of a process(I have its PID)

In my program I plan to iterate over the addresses and check if a specific pattern I have occurs in any string among the addresses.

I tried to search for libraries but unfortunately none of them worked for me or needed other extensions that neither worked.

Is there any way to do this simply?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this? If you want to directly access memory, Python may not be the best language to use.

Comment: Say there are in the process memory some strings: a, ab, abc. I want to check if at least one of those the pattern ab occurs. I have no problem with the pattern but instead I have problem with retrieving the strings from the process memory

Comment: Again, *why?* Why are you looking in memory? What do those strings represent? How will you convert the memory content into strings Python can use?  Please give some context, otherwise this is likely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I cannot tell why because it's a public and known program That's because I think that I found an information leak in the process memory If I can confirm this information leak through searching existence of common words related to this leak in this process memory I'll be able to be the first one reporting it  Is that possible with Python?

Comment: Long story short: probably not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe alright thanks